# Solution folder in Visual Studio 2010 does not build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

I have one solution with five projects and one solution folder. All project has a reference to project inside solution folder. When I clean solution and build, projects in solution folder does not build. I need to build project in solution folder before I build the solution.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a project is dependent on another project in your solution (not uncommon).

You can change the order that your projects build in Visual Studio so that the dependency tree is satisfied when building a solution.

If you right click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and choose 'Project Dependencies...' you will be able to tell Visual Studio which order to build your projects.

[image]